# Rails5, how to retry perform an ActiveJob a specific number of times (max attempts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job, rails-activejob

Right now I have my Background processes running with DelayedJobs, I see very convenient the `max_attempts` functionality on DelayedJob, how can I replicate this in ActiveJob?

Is this dependent on the queue system? has ActiveJob any abstraction configuration for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem [ActiveJob::Retry](https://github.com/isaacseymour/activejob-retry) did the trick:

```
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include ActiveJob::Retry.new(
    :strategy => :variable,
    :delays => [10.seconds, 1.minute, 10.minutes, 15.minutes]
  )
end
```